# How to create a large numbers of sockets for performance testing in Linux

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, sockets

I am developing a Linux based test tool for a custom application which will need to create roughly 200,000 sockets to an external system, then generate traffic over said sockets and create some performance metrics.

What I am wondering is the best approach to do this in Linux.  First, to have 200,000 sockets we would surely hit the FD limits.  Can the FD limit be increased this high (on a very powerful machine)?  Or what sort of reasonable maximum values can we expect to obtain per-Linux instance?

Also, the easiest first-thought for implementation of such a tool would be one thread per test client, which would create the connection, send traffic, measure performance, etc.  What sort of maximum numbers can we get for threads in the kernel?  Or does having several worker threads handling a subset of the endpoints make more sense?

Is this possible using one Linux implementation, or is splitting it out into multiple servers the only option?

Comment: I would use async IO for the client. You save the threads that way.

Comment: Which FD limit are you talking about? There are several different ones and which ones you're concerned about depend on how your application is constructed. What protocol are you using? The challenges with TCP are totally different from the ones with UDP.

Comment: Short of launching a DoS, (I'm going to regret asking this) you seriously don't need 200,000 *simultaneous* connections, right? Regardless, I'd use a thread-pool-backed work crew and an asio model.

Comment: 200,000 simultaneous client connections to an 'external system'?  This sounds very suspicious.

Comment: Sounds like a chat or live-update system. Nothing suspicious about it.

Comment: check out http://www.golinuxhub.com/2012/09/reset-hard-value-of-file-descriptors-in.html; should be possible to get over 200k descriptor on a 4-core machine

Comment: Not doing anything suspicious at all!  This is for testing some telecom/networking gear that terminates large numbers of mobile endpoints.  Unfortunately there is nothing out there to test this particular application with and we need to develop our own tool.  The transport will be TCP, actually (gasp) TLS (I know, I know, this will be difficult and we may need to use multiple servers).

Answer (score 2):

This problem is call "C10K" and it was extended when 10,000 connection were not a problem anymore. You can find lots of information in google.

On a strong linux machine (4 cpus, 16GB ram) you should be able to reach 1M.

The easiest way to handle such amount of open file descriptors is using `poll`. However, you will have to extend the limits of your host.

- ulimits
- kernel number of file descriptors
- size of socket buffer

See [C500K problem](http://urbanairship.com/blog/2010/09/29/linux-kernel-tuning-for-c500k/) documentation